# Particle system doesn't affect part of mesh?

Tags: particles

I'm trying to create a grass effect on a small landscape I've created. My current approach is to use a hair particle system, and style the hairs to look like grass. I've got a simple particle system added, and adjusted a few settings (note: I haven't made the grass green yet. It's just grey for now), but for some reason the particles don't go on certain parts of the mesh:
[image: Missing Particles]
You can see that to the left of the "lake" there is a lot of missing particles, in triangular areas. Although this screenshot was taken in rendered 3d view, it also has the same issue when I press the render button and do a "true" render. Here's some of the geometry:
[image: Geometry]

Any ideas why it isn't completely covered with particles?

Comment: Do you have any modifiers on the object.

Comment: Subdivision surface and particle

Comment: Did you check *use modifier stack* under the particle settings?

Comment: *facepalm* wow, I didn't see that option. This is the first time I've ever used particle systems, so I didn't really have any idea what I was doing. Thank you! It works after enabling that option. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: No worries!  You are definitely not the first person to overlook that setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure *use modifier stack* is checked under the *emission* rollout of the particle settings.

[image]

Comment: Please do not copy paste entire answers. Just mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @David  Sorry, I actually just used the same screenshot.  I wrote the answer without a screenshot and then remembered my old answer and decided to use the same picture.